# Background image in Mobile is not responsive

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, (Please don't judge it). So as it is a project which I have to submit, they will open my website on mobile as well as on PC.

I have used Bootstrap CSS and implemented some CSS for my background image, but the thing is that it looks epic on PC but very awful when I open it on my mobile.

**Here are some pics, when I open it on PC**

[image: Image on PC-1]

[image: Image on PC-2]

**And here are the same pics of my website when I open it on my Mobile phone, (without DesktopMode)**

[image: Image on Mobile-1]

**When I open it with DesktopMode on Mobile, It looks good but the background image is just not responsive enough**

[image: Image on Mobile with DesktopMode]

Below is the CSS styling code I have used:

```
<div
  class="
    position-relative
    overflow-hidden
    p-3 p-md-5
    m-md-3
    text-center
    bg-dark
  "
  style="
    color: white;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611716524065-622312678d68?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8c3BhY2V8fHx8fHwxNjM5MDYyNzc3&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=2048');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 30%;
  "
></div>
```

Please suggest to me some ways fix that awful look when the website is opened on Mobile because I don't have enough CSS Skills to do that. If I made any mistake please tell me to correct it. Thanks

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: yes you are correct, but I just have to ask for solutions as per my problem which is that, the website looks awful when I test it on my phone because of some css, there are many questions like this, but you are right it will require discussion and so on..

Comment: That library can help: https://www.jquery-backstretch.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello fellow developer,

There are many ways you can improve the design and ultimately get the satisfying result you want to achieve. I think you should notice and change a few things :

1. In this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3cJYm.jpg , You can see the background of the first div collide with the second division. If you can try to assign the first div and second div their own background-img. What I can assume is you are applying a background image to body/parent div and inside that div, you have another div with its own background.
2. Handle background on mobile view: Many times background images look good on desktop and look glitched on mobile such as the case with you. In such a case, you have to handle stretch, zoom, and content. You can find better knowledge on many blogs

But in your case, I think you should do something like following

```css
.back1{
background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611716524065-622312678d68?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8c3BhY2V8fHx8fHwxNjM5MDYyNzc3&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=2048');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #464646;
height: 70px;;
color : white;
}

.back2{
background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/gradient-colored-background-with-geometrical-shapes_23-2149112683.jpg');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #464646;
height: 70px;;
color : white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="back1"> YOUR CONTENT HERE - DIV 1 </div>
<div class="back2"> YOUR CONTENT HERE - DIV 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```